# ComboBox with button in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, combobox

how me create component ***button + combobox*** or already there is component on Delphi. **example: MSword>Open> there**

Comment: You need to provide example code of what you've tried and explain what problems you're having. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you need button with popup menu? Or combobox with additional button? Not everyone has MSWord(office) installed so it is not  a good example.

Comment: I think that he want something like "Office" button in MS Word  2007 i.e. `TRibbonApplicationMenuBar` in `Ribbon Controls`, but I'm not sure

Comment: Override SetButtonStyle and set BS_SPLITBUTTON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a TButton, set style to bsSplitButton, drop a popupmenu on the form and assign Button1.dropdownmenu with the popupmenu.

Comment: Delphi 7 does not have style property. That is since D2007 I think.

Comment: Oh yes, could be, I can't remember and it works also only for vista and later

Answer (score 0):

The very standard TComboBox has a button when the `Style` property is anything else than `csSimple`.

[image: Delphi 7 TComboBox (csDropDown)]